# HardHat Unable to download compiler versions list

Tags: javascript, dns, solidity, hardhat

So this is my first interaction with hardhat. I created a sample project using `npx hardhat` but for some reason, when I try to Run:

```
npx hardhat test
```

I get the following error:

```
Error HH502: Couldn't download compiler versions list. Please check your connection.
```

With the following error in the stack trace:

```
Caused by: FetchError: request to https://binaries.soliditylang.org/windows-amd64/list.json failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN binaries.soliditylang.org
```

So I tried navigating to binaries.soliditylang.org with Chrome and I found out that I'm getting `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

(I get this error even when I try to navigate to docs.soliditylang.org)

I understand it has something to do with DNS but I don't have a clue how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue. However, for me hardhat is not able to download list of compiler versions behind corporate proxy. Tried a lot of things. No luck. After a lot of trial and errors, found a way to make this work. Download `list.json`
and keep it locally at `C:\Users\<your-user>\AppData\Local\hardhat-nodejs\Cache\compilers\windows-amd64` (windows). Also, download the solidity compiler executable for windows (required version) from `https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases` and place it in the same folder mentioned above. Now, peruse your `list.json` and identify the object for the solc compiler version of interest. Rename the executable as with the long name given in `path` in that object. For e.g., if you need `solc` version `0.8.0`, the `path` in `list.json` for `0.8.0` version is `solc-windows-amd64-v0.8.4+commit.c7e474f2.exe`. Use this to rename the downloaded executable. Now, run `npm test`. This should fix the issue.

There is also an interesting way to run the compiler within docker on windows. For this, follow the discussion here - https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/1280

Answer (score 1):

Adding an .env file to the root of the project with

```
HTTPS_PROXY = ...
```

Solved in https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/pull/1291

Answer (score 0):

Had to `sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/<username>/Library/Caches/hardhat-nodejs` first.